# Using math with php data

Tags: php, math

Hi I'm trying to use yahoo to grab data then work out a formula in my head to come up with 2 numbers, but I can't figure out at what point and how to make these changes. Here is the code I found to help me get the actual numbers. First is yahoostock.php

```
    <?php
include_once('class.yahoostock.php');

$objYahooStock = new YahooStock;

/**
    Add format/parameters to be fetched

    p=previous close

    */
$objYahooStock->addFormat("p");

/**
    Add company stock code to be fetched
 */
$objYahooStock->addStock("TFM13.NYB");
foreach( $objYahooStock->getQuotes() as $code => $stock)
{
    ?>
    Previous Close: <?php echo $stock[0]; ?> <br />
    <?php
}
?>
```

And the second is class.yahoostock.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Class to fetch stock data from Yahoo! Finance
 *
 */

class YahooStock {

    /**
     * Array of stock code
     */
    private $stocks = array();

    /**
     * Parameters string to be fetched  
     */
    private $format;

    /**
     * Populate stock array with stock code
     *
     * @param string $stock Stock code of company   
     * @return void
     */
    public function addStock($stock)
    {
        $this->stocks[] = $stock;
    }

    /**
     * Populate parameters/format to be fetched
     *
     * @param string $param Parameters/Format to be fetched
     * @return void
     */
    public function addFormat($format)
    {
        $this->format = $format;
    }

    /**
     * Get Stock Data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getQuotes()
    {       
        $result = array();     
        $format = $this->format;

        foreach ($this->stocks as $stock)
        {           
            /**
             * fetch data from Yahoo!
             * s = stock code
             * f = format
             * e = filetype
             */
            $s = file_get_contents("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=$stock&f=$format&e=.csv");

            /**
             * convert the comma separated data into array
             */
            $data = explode( ',', $s);

            /**
             * populate result array with stock code as key
             */
            $result[$stock] = $data;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

My issue is I'm not completely sure as to at what point I would attempt to create a formula before output within the code. For example. Say I wanted to multiply by 2 then in a 'separate variable' to be outputted subtract 10 from the value before output. Where would I do this and what would it be called that I'm doing. I guess that may help to find more information on how to do it, but I'm having a hard time finding information through search on how to do it.
If this is confusing let me know. 
Any help as to how to do this is greatly appreciated and any reading is also greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, to make a formula, you just reuse variables and create new variables.  From the problem you're describing it sounds like you can do something like this:

set all the variables, then use them.

```
/* GET ALL VARIABLES FROM YAHOO AND CREATE YOUR VARIABLES*/
$var_1 = 500; //your variable pulled from yahoo
$multiplier = 2; //what you want to multiply by - you provide the number
$subtractor = 10; //what you want to subtract by - you provide the number

/* DO YOUR MATH */
$var_2 = $var_1 * $multiplier; //This will make a variable that multiplies var_1 and multiplier
$var_3 = $var_1 - $subtractor; //This will make a subtracted variable

/* OUTPUT YOUR VARIABLES */
echo $var_2;
echo $var_3;
```

You just get all the variables that you want and place them into php variables, then you do math with them by substituting the number with the variable name.  Then you can echo them out.  Or do whatever output you need.

Comment: thanks for the reply ntgCleaner. I can get that far, but I'm just not sure how to implement it into the code. I know the basics of php, but I can't seem to establish the connection in my head on how to apply two different sets of code as we now have here. Does that make sense? I should have been more clear that I've gotten this far, but I can't figure out how to apply them together. Specifically with what I have thus far with the above code.

Comment: If you call both pieces of code when you load your site, then you can use variables from either script.  When the page loads, it loads everything together, so technically, you can use variables from one in another, assuming you don't overwrite them.